# Adding a comment = audit failed?

Tags: discussion, bug, review-audits

I just failed [my first audit](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/772995) on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966987/indicator-icons-do-not-appear-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10).

I got the question in first post review where it was displayed without any comment, I began writing a comment suggesting to add a screenshot to clearify and draw attention. After that I wanted to upvote and move on, but instead I already failed the audit just because of my comment.

How is adding a comment wrong? I was under the impression that no matter whether the question is good or bad a comment suggesting useful improvements should always be appropriate. It's not as if I was up to leave a “Way to go” comment…

Comment: Strange! I once tried to add a comment to a post while doing a review task which was actually an audit, but as soon as I clicked on "*add a comment*" a tooltip-like overlay popped up saying "It's an audit".

Comment: That seems fair. If the very reason for audits is to make sure people are taking review serious, adding a comment instead of just voting should be equal to pass the audit IMO.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my first comment is wrong, hazy memories! I remember clearly that it showed "It's an audit", but I'm now confused whether I tried to add a comment or edit the post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @pomsky I've got that popup when trying to comment on audits

Comment: @muru Ah, thanks for confirming!

Comment: I have failed audits by adding a comment. no pop up about it being an audit

Comment: It depends which queue the audit is in. If it's close or reopen votes, IIRC, you get a popup (cc @pomsky), but I am surprised you failed by trying to comment, because I was under the impression the audit system had been adjusted lately so that trying to comment or edit would always pass (because those actions could be appropriate in any scenario).

Comment: @Zanna I'm relieved this isn't default and desired behaviour – should I file a bug anywhere then?

Comment: We can report bugs here on meta (using the [bug] tag) but I'm probably just wrong about comments always passing, since I can't find any documentation. I am pretty sure the audit system was adjusted to do fewer nonsensical failures, and I think it was after one user brought up an issue like this in chat, and since then I've never failed an audit by trying to comment, but I haven't found any real evidence, so I might just be imagining things >_<

Comment: @zanna -- I just had another one. leaving a comment equals fail on the audit. After failing, the system revealed the comments made on the post, and my comment was almost identical to the first comment made.

Comment: @ravery which queue were you reviewing in?

Comment: @zanna -- low quality posts I think it was. a question about "./"

Comment: @ravery it was [here in first posts](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/779886). So I was wrong. I thought commenting on even a "high quality post" would pass

Comment: @zanna -- yes that one

Comment: @zana --  everytime I have commented in an audit I have failed. almost makes you not want to comment while reviewing.

Comment: It works well in the CV queue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPRLA.png

Comment: In my case, question was https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222971/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-laptop-with-soldered-ram-module-that-has-damaged-cell and my comment was 'You dare not, repair it first!' what else I could do about it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't fret, you're not alone, all of us have failed the occasional tricky audit. Some of them are, what I call bad audits, but to stop people from robot reviewing they are a good thing and that is what counts. Being myself annoyed with audits from time to time, yep even failing some. Doesn't keep me from reviewing.

One rule of thumb you should go for when reviewing, when in doubt, re-read the question or answer in its original form, this is what the Link link is for beside it.

Check its edit history if your still in doubt then, maybe a flag or vote was cast on an question/answer in a much worse state and an edit resolved that later on.

And all be the way you will catch the audits in most cases and not fail them. so you payed attention to an question/answer. As we should put research into our questions we ask and answers we give, reviewing others needs as well the same kind of research.