# The review-queue audit-system fails users for making a comments

Tags: support, review-queue

Why does adding a comment to a good post prompt this message.

> STOP! Look and Listen. This was an audit, designed to see if you were
>   paying attention. You didn't pass. Your review was inappropriate. This
>   was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it
>   as-is or even upvoting.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but
>   please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the
>   guidance above.

I looked at the question, it seemed like a question that would have already been answered, a quick google and the first hit showed an answer on the unix stackexchange. I provided a comment and a link to to the post. However I was flagged by the audit system. I feel that adding a comment is not reason to fail an audit since my understating is that linking to answers on other stack-exchange sites is the proper way to handle such situations and many good question will have the same question on other sites. Was I in the wrong here or is this a weakness in the audit system. If it is a weakness maybe could this be fixed by checking to see if the user is linking to another stack exchange site.

Here is the question that I was reviewing. [Run a command that requires sudo after a time has passed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119144/run-a-command-that-requires-sudo-after-a-time-has-passed)

I realize this was deceased in [adding a comment = audit failed](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17430/adding-a-comment-audit-failed) but I'm wondering about the providing links case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a weakness in the audit system. One of many. Don't worry about it, these audits are only there to catch people who are clicking blindly to get badges. Failing one every now and then is not an issue, just shake your head at the stupidity of all automated systems and move on to the next review item.